# Unable to share File Object publicly even though ACL is set

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

we're using `@google-cloud/storage` @ `2.3.1` and want to make uploaded files publicly accessible.

We create our File objects using the `createWriteStream` method as per this example:

```
gcFile.createWriteStream({
  predefinedAcl: 'publicRead',
});
```

However, the file still shows `Not public` in the `Public access` column:
[image]

We decided to try the `public` boolean while creating the stream as per the [API reference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File#createWriteStream) (which is actually an alias for the above) - with the file not resulting in being publicly accessible:

```
gcFile.createWriteStream({
  public: true,
});
```

Next, we tried to make the file public using the `makePublic` method on the `File` object:

```
const file = gcs.bucket('our_bucket_name').file('file_path_here');
await file.makePublic();
const acl = await file.acl.get();
console.log(acl);
```

This logs following ACL for the object:

```
[
  [
    { 
      entity: 'owner@our-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
      role: 'OWNER'
    },
    { 
      entity: 'allUsers', 
      role: 'READER' 
    }
  ],
  { 
    kind: 'storage#objectAccessControls',
    items: 
      [ 
        [Object], 
        [Object] 
      ] 
  }
]
```

So it looks like we've met following condition [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console?hl=en_GB#_sharingdata):

```
The Access Control List (ACL) for the object includes an entry for 
allUsers or allAuthenticatedUsers.

If these conditions are met, the public access column for the object 
reads Public.`
```

However, the column still reads `Not public`.

Altough the permissions look correct, we've also checked the permissions in the Cloud Console by following [the steps described here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#changing-acls).

When editing permissions, it states clearly that the object is publicly accessible, however it doesn't show a public link in the overview?
[image]

We are able to get the file public by setting public access on a Bucket-level, but we really like it to be on a per-object level. How can we get this to work?

Comment: Thanks for posting...Same thing happening here.

Comment: [this page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data) describes how to access public shared objects using following url formatting (check the API link part): `http://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]`. Funny this is: that actually works, even though the Cloud Storage Browser is still displaying `Not public` in the column `Public access`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that was resolved yesterday. Thanks for raising a question!

Cheers!

Comment: coming through correctly now - thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is adding *allUsers* to the bucket's following permissions: Storage Object Viewer, Storage Legacy Object Reader.

They do not allow the public to list the bucket but read objects **inside** the bucket.

[Permissions on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEevB.png)

Comment: hi Kago, thanks for chiming in - that works indeed, what you descibe is called _Making groups of objects publicly readable_ [described here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#storage-make-object-public-nodejs).
On the same page, there's a guide to do it on a per-object basis (_Making individual objects publicly readable_). It looks to us that it should also be possible without changing permissions on the bucket level.